# Calling times() in kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel, posix, kernel-module, system-calls

I am developing a kernel module, and I need to get an approximate value of the CPU time consumed by some process (iterating the processes is not an issue). Specifically, I want the same behavior provided by the libc [`clock`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock) or the [`times`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/times) syscall. I tried calling [`do_sys_times`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/time.h#L154) but seems it's not exported (undefined symbol when compiled).

Is there a way to call [`times`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/times) inside a kernel module? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552536/get-current-time-in-seconds-in-kernel-module

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I want the elapsed per-process CPU clock ticks (see man 2 times). The post you linked to asked for the wallclock time in seconds.

Comment: Ah I think I see now. Maybe you can try reading this information out of somewhere in /proc as a quick hack (assuming you can access files from inside a kernel module).

Comment: Kernel modules typically do not care about processes. Why can't you call `times()` from userspace? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I cannot control the processes. The module needs to monitor the ticks consumed by arbitrary processes whenever they leave the scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want precisely measure times between some events in kernel (like context switching), you need some tracer, like [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/). From kernel module you may directly bind probes through various tracing and profiling subsystems like ftrace, perf or kprobes.

Here is an example which dumps message to kernel log when context is switched:

```
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/tracepoint.h>

#include <trace/events/sched.h>

...

void my_sched_switch_probe(void* ignore, struct task_struct* prev, struct task_struct* next) {
    printk("my_sched_switch_probe: %s -> %s at %lu\n", prev->comm, next->comm, 
        (unsigned long) sched_clock());
}

int cswtracer_init(void) {
    register_trace_sched_switch(my_sched_switch_probe, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void cswtracer_fini(void) {
    unregister_trace_sched_switch(my_sched_switch_probe, NULL);
}

module_init(cswtracer_init);
module_exit(cswtracer_fini);
```

NOTE: do not run it, it will slow your system dramatically.

So analyze name of processes in `my_sched_switch_probe()` and calculate difference between time when process entered CPU (`next->comm == "myprocessname"`) and when it leaves CPU (`prev->comm == "myprocessname"`). That difference is the last time period process spent on CPU during.