# Edit Linux Kernel Packet Sending and Receiving

Tags: c, linux, kernel, packet, raspberry-pi3

I'm looking to add timestamp functionality to sending and receiving packets in a Raspberry Pi in order to measure clock skew. I am having trouble finding the correct functions to modify to get accurate readings. The code is open source and can be found [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.1.y/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmfmac).

Help on which functions to target when trying to accomplish this is appreciated.

Comment: `clock_gettime` is no good? Or perhaps you need a kernel equivalent? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552536/get-current-time-in-seconds-in-kernel-module

Comment: not the function to get the timestamps, what i am looking for are the kernel level functions that create and send/receive packets so that i can modify them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving and transmitting packets by using skb structure then probably you can extract the time stamping from the SKB structure by using following linux library function.
do_gettimeofday(&skb->stamp);

if you are not using skb then check your structure must be similar fashion.
Thanks 
Karn